# Combobox dropping up?

Tags: winapi, combobox

Is there a way to make combobox be dropping up instead of down?

Comment: I've got a feeling this is handled by the OS, depending on if it has space to display the combo box in its normal manner.

Comment: Sure, but how to change the behavior?

Comment: Move the parent window close to the bottom of the screen :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have answered that Q but it's in Delphi (the code is not so hard to understand though):

[Can I programmatically set the position of ComboBox dropdown list?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9165643/937125)

You need to subclass the ComboBox `hwndList` (You obtain that handle via  [`GetComboBoxInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775939.aspx) API) using `SetWindowLong` (`GWL_WNDPROC`) and handle `WM_MOVE` message to place that `hwndList` in a new position.

Answer (score 1):

Not with the standard Windows combo boxes (Here are the available [styles for combo boxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775796.aspx)).

As @ILMV said, Windows will drop the box up instead of down if there is not enough space below the box.

You can test this with notepad - go to format -> font, and drag the box down so that the Script combo box is just above the start menu. Click the combo box - it drops up.

If you want it to *always* drop up, you'll have to make your own.

Comment: What I really want is an idea like in-process overriding API functions, used by the combo for requesting screen height. Is there anything simpler?