# Is there a way to track scroll bar messages from TComboBox?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, combobox, delphi-6

In my extended `TComboBox` class, I overrided `ComboWndProc()` procedure handler, but I was not able to detect neither CN_VSCROLL nor WM_VSCROLL messages from the scroll bar of the List (`FListHandle`).

I basically want to implement an infinite scroll using winapi.
I imagine that, to do what I want, I basically would need to know the track bar position of the scroll so when the track bar touch the line down button I would add more data to strings.

The idea is simple and maybe naive, but I could start from there and see what problems I would have.

Is it possible to do such a thing?

**Is there a way to track scroll bar messages from TComboBox?**

More importantly:

- If yes, **How**?
- If no, **Why**?

Comment: Alternatives are welcome too, just saying

Comment: Surely you need ListWndProc. And I cannot see you getting any CN_XXX messages. I'd expect this to be a pure Win32 window.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ListWndProc just calls ComboWndProc. I wondered that, I think those messages never reaches the list handle

Comment: And what Style is your combo? In case that matters

Comment: @DavidHeffernan csDropDown

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Shouldn't I be able to see those messages? According to docs: _The WM_VSCROLL message is sent to a window when a scroll event occurs in the window's standard vertical scroll bar. **This message is also sent to the owner of a vertical scroll bar control** when a scroll event occurs in the control._.

Comment: ListWndProc is the window procedure of a simple combobox, which the listbox part is a child of the combobox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `WM_VSCROLL`, to do so you have to subclass the listbox control of the combobox. `CN_VSCROLL` will not work because the listbox part of the combobox is not a VCL control.

Below example is essentially from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9165643) of Kobik, included here for the sake of completeness.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FComboListWnd: HWND;
    FComboListWndProc, FSaveComboListWndProc: Pointer;
    procedure ComboListWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Info: TComboBoxInfo;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@Info, SizeOf(Info));
  Info.cbSize := SizeOf(Info);
  GetComboBoxInfo(ComboBox1.Handle, Info);
  FComboListWnd := Info.hwndList;
  FComboListWndProc := classes.MakeObjectInstance(ComboListWndProc);
  FSaveComboListWndProc := Pointer(GetWindowLong(FComboListWnd, GWL_WNDPROC));
  SetWindowLong(FComboListWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, Longint(FComboListWndProc));
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetWindowLong(FComboListWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, Longint(FSaveComboListWndProc));
  classes.FreeObjectInstance(FComboListWndProc);
end;

procedure TForm1.ComboListWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  case Message.Msg of
    WM_VSCROLL: OutputDebugString('scrolling');
  end;
  Message.Result := CallWindowProc(FSaveComboListWndProc,
      FComboListWnd, Message.Msg, Message.WParam, Message.LParam);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I believe I can manage to make it work now

Comment: By the way, how did you knew the list is child of the of the desktop window. How can I learn more about it? This kind of knowledge only comes with practice? May I read about it somewhere?

Comment: @epro - I guess the most you can find documented is that the listbox control is some 'ComboLBox'. Other than that you may find pieces here and there. What I do to quickly examine volatile popups like this (menu, etc..) is to construct an owner-drawn one and put a breakpoint in drawing code. Then you can freeze the window and try spy++ on it. It's kind of delicate though, when I also include message processing, this setup sometimes manages to freeze the entire box. Otherwise, if you can subclass the window then you can do whatever you want.. You're welcome!